# seaborn joyplot does not fill all the way to the top

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, ridgeline-plot

I'm using `seaborn` in Python 3.5. Taking the example joy plot from the gallery, modified slightly to save the figure:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="white", rc={"axes.facecolor": (0, 0, 0, 0)})

# Create the data
rs = np.random.RandomState(1979)
x = rs.randn(500)
g = np.tile(list("ABCDEFGHIJ"), 50)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=x, g=g))
m = df.g.map(ord)
df["x"] += m

# Initialize the FacetGrid object
pal = sns.cubehelix_palette(10, rot=-.25, light=.7)
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="g", hue="g", aspect=15, size=.5, palette=pal)

# Draw the densities in a few steps
g.map(sns.kdeplot, "x", clip_on=False, shade=True, alpha=1, lw=1.5, bw=.2)
g.map(sns.kdeplot, "x", clip_on=False, color="w", lw=2, bw=.2)
g.map(plt.axhline, y=0, lw=2, clip_on=False)

# Define and use a simple function to label the plot in axes coordinates
def label(x, color, label):
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.text(0, .2, label, fontweight="bold", color=color,
            ha="left", va="center", transform=ax.transAxes)

g.map(label, "x")

# Set the subplots to overlap
g.fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=-.25)

# Remove axes details that don't play will with overlap
g.set_titles("")
g.set(yticks=[])
g.despine(bottom=True, left=True)
plt.savefig('tmp.png')
```

There is a slight visual defect, namely the KDEs do not quite fill all the way to the top. This is most visible in rows B, G, H and J:

[image]

Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem here. matplotlib 2.2.2, TkAgg backend,  Numpy 1.14.2, Pandas 0.22.0, seaborn 0.8.1., Python 3.5.2, Ubuntu 16.04